# XSLT copy the entire contents of an XML with 2 (or more) exceptions

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I've got an large input XML that I want to make smaller for a particular client. The client should only see information relevant to him. Here is the example input.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<reg>
<global>stuff</global>
<profile>
<profile_data>profile stuff 1</profile_data>
<users>
<u><usr_data>usr options 1</usr_data><n>user-1</n></u>
<u><usr_data>usr options 2</usr_data><n>user-2</n></u>
</users>
</profile>
<profile>
<profile_data>profile stuff 2</profile_data>
<users>
<u><usr_data>usr options 3</usr_data><n>user-3</n></u>
<u><usr_data>usr options 4</usr_data><n>user-4</n></u>
</users>
</profile>
</reg>
```

This needs to be transformed into a smaller XML that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<reg>
<global>stuff</global>
<profile>
<profile_data>profile stuff 1</profile_data>
<users>
<u><usr_data>usr options 1</usr_data><n>user-1</n></u>
</users>
</profile>
</reg>
```

I've managed to accomplish this using 2 XSLT transformations applied in series (trans1.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:param name="name"/>
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/reg/profile">
    <xsl:if test="./users/*/n=$name">
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and (trans2.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:param name="name"/>
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/reg/profile/users/*">
    <xsl:if test="./n=$name">
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then:

```
xsltproc -param name "'user-1'" trans1.xml input.xml > out1.xml
xsltproc -param name "'user-1'" trans2.xml out1.xml > result.xml
```

How can I convert my 2 XSl stylesheets into 1 to perform these 2 operations in 1 step.

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pName" select="'user-1'"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="profile">
  <xsl:if test="users/u/n = $pName">
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="u">
  <xsl:if test="n = $pName">
   <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<reg>
    <global>stuff</global>
    <profile>
        <profile_data>profile stuff 1</profile_data>
        <users>
            <u>
                <usr_data>usr options 1</usr_data>
                <n>user-1</n>
            </u>
            <u>
                <usr_data>usr options 2</usr_data>
                <n>user-2</n>
            </u>
        </users>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <profile_data>profile stuff 2</profile_data>
        <users>
            <u>
                <usr_data>usr options 3</usr_data>
                <n>user-3</n>
            </u>
            <u>
                <usr_data>usr options 4</usr_data>
                <n>user-4</n>
            </u>
        </users>
    </profile>
</reg>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<reg>
   <global>stuff</global>
   <profile>
      <profile_data>profile stuff 1</profile_data>
      <users>
         <u>
            <usr_data>usr options 1</usr_data>
            <n>user-1</n>
         </u>
      </users>
   </profile>
</reg>
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use and overriding of the **[identity rule](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)**.